# Could a metric space X be sequentially compact if one sequence in X has no convergent subsequence?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In Kreyszig compactness of metric space X is defined as :

> A metric space X is said to be compact if every sequence in X has a convergent subsequence.

My confusion is simply because of the use of the `if` in the statement. Consider the sentence:

> Statement A if Statement B.

This means that if Statement B is true then Statement A is true, but if Statement B is false, Statement A may or may not be true (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if#Distinction_from_%22if%22_and_%22only_if%22)). I feel that the `if` in the definition should be replaced by the `only if`.

Comment: I think it is common to simply write “if” for definitions.

Comment: Here your first statement "$X$ is compact" would not be an actual statement, since the term "compact" is not defined yet. As nejimban said, it is an usual way to write definitions.